# Get div with certain attribute - Scrapy selector

Tags: scrapy

I have HTML that looks like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <dl>
      <dt>Prerequisites</dt>
      <dd>15-510</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <dl>
      <dt>Corequisites</dt>
      <dd>None</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to get the value inside `<dd>` based on the corresponding `<dt>`. For example, I want to do something like select 'Prerequisites' and get '15-510'.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you avoided of using jquery?

Comment: Yeah. I'm using Scrapy so this is happening in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `xpath("//dt[text() = 'Prerequisites']/following-sibling::dd")`?

Comment: I don't know why I never thought of using text() = ...
Thanks a lot. It works!